# Springboot GSP - Tag [form] does not exist. No tag library found for namespace: g

Tags: java, forms, spring-boot, gsp

I'm writing a website using Springboot (java) and GSP.

I've managed to get GSP working for the most part, dependencies installing fine, layouts/templates working etc

However when I try and use the `<g:form>` tag, I get an error:

Tag [form] does not exist. No tag library found for namespace: g

The code I'm using:

```
<g:form name="myForm" action="/users/register" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</g:form>
```

To eliminate the possibility that it's a problem with running gsp entirely, I've tried using the `<g:each>`....`</g:each>` tag, and that worked perfectly well.

The grails dependency version I have is 2.5.2
The groovy dependency version I have is 2.4.4

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

GSP Spring Boot does not support the Form tag library and many other GSP features and is not actively maintained. There are many things to be changed and configured to get the same experience as you get when you use GSP with Grails.

That's why we created [Rabbtor](http://knowledgebase.rabbytes.com/display/rabbtordoc/GSP+%28+Groovy+Server+Pages+%29+Template+Engine). Please see the link for the documentation on what we did, why , and how you can use it.